# International English keyboard in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard-layout

I need to use the International English keyboard, as I constantly write in both English and Spanish throughout the day.

When I installed 8.1 a few days ago, it asked me for my keyboard preference, and I selected the international English setting. I thought I was all set.

Now, I do not see any language on the bottom bar (in 8.0 I could see when it switched itself back to US English) and it seems stuck in US English.

I do not want to switch to the Spanish keyboard, as it's not the same as the actual keys. The International English setting worked fine for me all through my Windows 7 years. How can I get it permanently on this Windows 8.1 computer?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You have both language packs installed correct?  8.1 handles this functionality **EXACTLY** the same as 8.0

Answer (score -1):

Go to:

1. PC settings.
2. Time and language.
3. Region and language.
4. Under 'Languages', click 'Add a language'.
5. Choose the secondary language you want to use, in your case Spanish.

Your notification area will now have an 'Input Indicator', similar to before, that lets you quickly switch between languages/keyboard layouts.

**EDIT:** I misread your question, however, following steps 1 to 4 and selecting the language you want as the default, then removing 'English (United States)' from the 'Languages' section should solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you, Andy. I followed your instructions, and added English UK, then went to Options and selected International and downloaded the language pack. Initially, I selected International in English US and I selected Spanish and English UK, but it turned my keyboard into the Spanish keyboard though I hadn't specified it as the primary one. I deleted Spanish and Eng US, but now Word underlines all in red and it doesn't accept Spanish accents. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I just tried it again. I added Eng US and selected the International QWERTY option. I deleted the standard Eng US and then I removed Eng UK. I am now able to use accents correctly. I hope this has resolved the issue. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Word, however, continues to show all my text underlined in red and I have it set to US English as the default.

Comment: In Word, go to 'File', 'Options', 'Language'. Under 'Choose Editing Languages' you can have different languages set for the keyboard layout and proofing.